# Carry the values of the form to the next's page form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cookies, input

I have tried to save input values of a form on my index page and carry them to the booking page in cookies using JavaScript, but it didn't work.

The form at index.html is:

```
  <form id="check-book" name="check-book" method="post" action="/book.html" onsubmit="return storeValues(this);">
  <fieldset>
  <label for="field_date_in">Дата заезда:</label> 
   <input type="text" id="field_date_in" size="8" readonly="readonly" name="sender_checkin"/>
   <label for="field_date_out">Дата выезда:</label>
   <input type="text" id="field_date_out" size="8" readonly="readonly" name="sender_checkout"/>
   <input type="submit" name="send_message" value="Забронировать!">
  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

which I need to carry to the booking page form:

```
<form id="booking-form" name="contact-form" action="send-mail.php" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Контактная Информация</legend>
   <label for="field_name">Имя:</label>
   <input type="text" id="field_name" name="sender_name" placeholder="Введите Ваше Имя" autofocus/>
   <label for="field_email">E-mail:</label> 
   <input type="text" id="field_email"  pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3,}@[a-zA-Z]{3,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}" title="Пожалуйста введите e-mail" name="sender_email" placeholder="Введите Ваш e-mail">   
   <label for="field_phone">Номер телефона:</label> 
   <input type="text" id="field_phone" name="sender_phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш Номер Телефона" >
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Информаци о бронировании</legend>
   <label for="room_selector">Выберите номер:</label><select name="room_selector" id="room_selector">
   <option value="eco_twin">Эконом (Две кровати)</option>
   <option value="std_twin">Стандарт (Две кровати)</option>
   <option value="std_double">Стандарт (Двойная кровать)</option>
   <option value="attic_twin">Эконом Мансарда (Две кровати)</option>
       <option value="attic_double">Эконом Мансарда (Двойная кровать)</option>
   <option value="lux_twin">Люкс (Две кровати)</option>
   <option value="lux_double">Люкс (Двойная кровать)</option>
   <option value="lux_wed">Люкс Свадебный</option>
   <option value="lux_lux">Суперлюкс</option>
   </select>
   <label for="field_date_in">Дата заезда:</label>
   <input type="text" id="field_date_in" size="8" readonly="readonly" name="sender_checkin"/>
   <label for="field_date_out">Дата выезда:</label>
   <input type="text" id="field_date_out" size="8" readonly="readonly" name="sender_checkout"/>
   <label for="field_guests">Количество гостей:</label>
   <input type="number" step="1" value="1" min="1" max="100" id="field_guests" name="sender_guests" />
   <label for="field_message">Сообщение:</label>
   <textarea id="field_message" name="sender_message" rows="5" cols="50">    </textarea><br>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset> 
   <input type="submit" name="send_message" value="Отправить">
  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

and the JavaScript I tried was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Original JavaScript code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
  // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

  var today = new Date();
  var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

  function setCookie(name, value)
  {
    document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" +         expiry.toGMTString();
  }

</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function storeValues(form)  
    {
    setCookie("field_date_in", form.field_date_in.value);
    setCookie("field_date_out", form.field_date_out.value);
     return true;
    }

</script>
```

Now, how can I upload the values of index.html form to the book.html by using the stored cookies? (Assuming they are stored). I am very new to JavaScript and cookies for me are something that I either eat with coffee or clean when the browser is lagging.

Comment: Where are you calling `storeValues` in your code?

Comment: do you have a getCookie func set up?  Youll need one

Comment: Eeeem, I believe the getCookie is something like:

    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Original JavaScript code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
      // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

      function getCookie(name)
      {
        var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
        var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
        return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
      }

     </script>
(Not sure how right it is) But how do I get the cookies to fill in the right fields in the form?